# Auth0 Hosted Page Launch Sign Up Tab

Tags: reactjs, authentication, auth0

I am using the Auth0-js package v9.1 to connect to my React app to a Hosted Page, which internally using Auth0Lock to customize user signup parameters.

What I would like to do is have a link to go to the login tab, and a separate button to connect directly to the Sign Up tab.  Is this kind of control possible?

I have a AuthService wrapper class which I'm using to launch the Auth0 Lock client currently.

```
export class AuthService() {
  constructor() {
    this.auth0 = new auth0.WebAuth(
                   {
                     domain:       AUTH0_DOMAIN,
                     clientID:     AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
                     redirectUri:  AUTH0_REDIRECT_URL,
                     audience:     AUTH0_AUDIENCE_URL,
                     responseType: 'token id_token',
                     scope:        'openid profile email'
                   }
                 )
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    // Check whether the session has past the
    // access token's expiry time
    return ( ! this.isSessionExpired() )
  }


  // display the Auth0 lock modal and allow the user to log in
  login() {
    this.auth0.authorize()
  }

  ...
}

export default new AuthService
```

What I would like to have is a method which links directly to the Sign Up tab, so I can call it from a specialize component

```
 ....
   signup() {
     this.auth0.authorize('signup')
     - or alternatively -
     this.auth0.signup()
   }
 ....
```

Is something like this possible?  How would I go about linking directly to that Sign Up tab?

Thx

Comment: It is possible, but not very obvious. Here is how: https://community.auth0.com/t/how-to-open-login-signup-on-the-universal-login-hosted-page/12642/7 https://community.auth0.com/t/lock-js-how-to-default-tab-to-sign-up/6786